# Populating joined tables with blanks SQL

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am relatively new to SQL so please be gentle! I have a table that holds by month a list of statuses for a particular structure element. This only holds records where a status has been changed (for example agreed) so I am missing information for when something has not been started at all (which won't exist in the table as there has been no action in the table). Basically I want to join this to another table that holds dates, so that if there are no records it populates the status with a blank.

For example Table A holds the statuses

```
Cycle ID ....  Status  
69082 ............2  
80412 ............3
```

Table B holds the dates

```
Cycle ID..... Date  
69082 ..........October 2013  
75520 ..........November 2013  
80045 ..........December 2013  
80412 ..........January 2014
```

So the output I want would be something like this (so a record for everything from Table B and a blank status where something doesn't exist in Table A):

```
Cycle ID .... Date .... Status  
69082 ........Oct 13.....2  
75520 ........Nov13.....' '  
80045 ........Dec13 ....' '  
80412 ........Jan14 .....3
```

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think a right join on Table A will give you those columns

Comment: I've tried right joins, left joins (all of them basically!) and it was only returning records where there were records in both.

Comment: Okay, did you try with inner join and add TableA.status in the select?

Comment: This is the exact code I'm trying to use:  

    SELECT
      a.BUDGET_STATE_HISTORY_ID As ID,
      b.vis_id,
      a.STRUCTURE_ELEMENT_ID,
      a.PREVIOUS_STATE,
      a.NEW_STATE,
      a.CHANGED_TIME
    FROM BUDGET_STATE_HISTORY a

    RIGHT JOIN BUDGET_CYCLE b on b.budget_cycle_id =     a.budget_cycle_id

where b.model_ID = '1' and a.structure_element_id = '1057'

Answer (score 0):

You can use Case-Then-Else statement

```
Select 
  tb.cycleid ,
  tb.date ,
  Case 
    When tb.status is Null Then ''
    Else tb.status /* cast to string! */
  End as status
From tableB tb left outer join tableA ta on ta.cycleid=tb.cycleid
```

Depending on your database you must cast to string the status value. For example in sql server you can use `CAST(tb.status as varchar(3))` over the `Else` part.

Review the join-clause. The above query will get all the cycles that have a `date`. If a cycle doesn't figures in Table B (not has a date) it won't appear in the result. Also maybe you need to use `distinct` for do not repeat cycles with more than one date.